# Iterating the assignment of a variable's name

Tags: c#, variables, variable-assignment

So this is something I've always wondered..

Say I want 10 threads called t1 t2 t3 etc... But I don't want to write

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(run);
Thread t2 = new Thread(run);
Thread t3 = new Thread(run);
...
```

Rather something like this: (pseudo-code)

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    Thread t + i = new Thread(run);
}
```

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Okay, so this is basically what I wanted to do:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int n = 0;
        Program p = new Program();
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            threads.Add(new Thread(p.run));
        }

        foreach(Thread t in threads)
        {
            n++;
            t.Name = "Thread " + n;
            t.IsBackground = true;
            t.Start();
        }

        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
```

Thanks all!

Comment: What's the end goal?  Just to have 10 threads?

Comment: This is why arrays and List<T>'s exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. Why not just this?

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++){
    new Thread(run);
}
```

If you really want to keep references to each thread, you can store them in a list.

Comment: Hmm... I suppose this would work, while adding each one to a list while iterating... Okay, thanks!